# OpenGL ES 2.0 - Draw Line with Texture?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es-2.0

What is the best approach for drawing a Line with a specific texture?

Right now I'm attempting to draw a Line with a texture by simply drawing lines instead of another Primitive.

```
    setupMandatoryHandlers(shader);

    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionHandler);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(positionHandler, COORDS, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, STRIDE, vertexBuffer);

    if (texture != null)
        setupTextureData();     

    GLES20.glUniform4fv(colorHandler, 1, color, 0);

    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(MVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, orthoMatrix, 0);       
    GLES20.glDrawElements(drawType, indices.length, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indexBuffer);

    GLRenderer.CheckGLError("Draw Elements");       

    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(positionHandler);

    if (texture != null)
        GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(texCoordHandler);
```

Is this the most efficient way of drawing lines with textures or should I be looking somewhere else? Should I use `glDrawArrays` instead of `glDrawElements` for lines?

Comment: Didn't read the question as I don't know anything about OpenGL but...aren't lines 2-dimensional in OpenGL, i.e. no textures?

Comment: 2 dimensional primitives can have textures? That's how you would draw a Quad

Comment: Sorry, I meant 1-dimensional (only length)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To draw a texture on a line you either have to use `PointSprites` or draw small textured Quads. In my case I used `Triangle_Strips` and textured those because the line in my case could be small and still look exactly like a line.

If anyone has a better solution or has implemented the above feel free to post an answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can't texture a 1D line with a simple texture because there no way, as far as I know, to get the current pixel position of the line the fragment shader it is currently drawing.

Comment: Actually it is. If you assume no multisampling, then gl_FragCoord.xy will give pixel position in 0..1 coordinates - multiply it by viewport (width, height) and you'll get pixel position.

Comment: You can try to use `gl_FragCoord.xy` and then get the texture color from a `sampler2D` with these coordinates.